# Extracting data from a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the below code in which i am reading a text file and trying to extract the required data. However, I am getting error 'expected string or bytes-like object'.

Since I cannot attach the file, I am pasting the text file contents over here:

```
FIRCOSOFT-FOF-ProCESS
HDR ./INPUT/201911098765-SWFTNA-ID3751V1_1.DAT    65764645454 FMFILE LINUX  5.7.2.1
H   156898900   0         50K     0 6 -1 WCP002862      1   WORLDCHECK-PREMIUM    EMBARGOJHUHUGHJHHHHHHHH KHH,KHHUHJ
## $$$$ 
\000000\0000000000000000000000000000000\00000000000   NO :20:9E40FGTE23555CEasw3NN :23B: IHDUHFUEHRUEURH99090SNDNNDB
2019-04-15 FCMBATCH  0101010 01 01 01 0 1 01
```

My code:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop')
file=open("Test_data.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
file.read()
a=re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:')
z=a.findall(file)
```

Kindly help me with a solution. I want to extract words between `:20:` and `:23B:` from the attached text file and put them into excel file with a column named text_id.

```
Excel output ---

text_id
9E40FGTE23555CEasw3NN
```

Comment: Kindly reformat your question to a presentable state. Separate code from file content. Separate code from part of the question. Invest more than 3 secs if you expect someone to help you for more than 3 secs.

Comment: do you even english

Answer (score 1):

Open your file and read its content:

```
with open("Test_data.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
    text = fobj.read()
```

Now, apply your regex to the read text (not the file object):

```
a = re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:')
z = a.findall(text)
```

and `z` contains `['9E40FGTE23555CEasw3NN']`.

Comment: Nice one @Mike Müller. If I unsterstand correctly the regular expression (.*) lets you pick everything between :20 and :23B right?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have total 90 text files with similar data. I need to extract two fields, 1.) Anything between :20: and :23B: 2.) Anything between WCP and WORLDCHECK-PREMIUM. I am using the below code, it is extracting the first part but not the second one. Using this code-- os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop') s=open("Total_data.txt","r",encoding='UTF-8') y=s.read() a=re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:') b=re.compile('WCP(.*)WORLDCHECK-') z=a.findall(y) k=b.findall(y) print(k) ..........................................Can you pleaSE HELP? Also, how can i avoid an error when there is no match?

Answer (score 0):

file.read() has been used, but the read value is not accessed, try using `file=file.read`,
it shall do the trick

[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGQA1.png)

Comment: You might want to post your sample as actual code instead of an image

Comment: Thanks for this. I have total 90 text files with similar data. I need to extract two fields, 1.) Anything between :20: and :23B: 2.) Anything between WCP and WORLDCHECK-PREMIUM. I am using the below code, it is extracting the first part but not the second one. Using this code-- os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop') s=open("Total_data.txt","r",encoding='UTF-8') y=s.read() a=re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:') b=re.compile('WCP(.*)WORLDCHECK-') z=a.findall(y) k=b.findall(y) print(k) ..........................................Can you pleaSE HELP? Also, how can i avoid an error when there is no match?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a file but not assigning the value to a variable by just writing `file.read()`, instead you should assign the value to a variable and close the file after finishing the operation like:

```py
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop')
file=open("Test_data.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
data = file.read()
file.close()
a=re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:')
z=a.findall(data)
```

Also a quick suggestion, you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/J7FVM2/1) `:.*:(.*?) *:.*:` as the value `:20:` might include letters or maybe not.
With some cleanup, your code can be written like this:

```py
import re, os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop')

with open("Test_data.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

a = re.compile(':.*:(.*?) *:.*:')
z = a.findall(data)
```

**Output:**

```py
['9E40FGTE23555CEasw3NN']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have total 90 text files with similar data. I need to extract two fields, 1.) Anything between :20: and :23B: 2.) Anything between WCP and WORLDCHECK-PREMIUM. I am using the below code, it is extracting the first part but not the second one. Using this code-- os.chdir('C:\\Users\\waliaar\\Desktop') s=open("Total_data.txt","r",encoding='UTF-8') y=s.read() a=re.compile(':20:(.*) :23B:') b=re.compile('WCP(.*)WORLDCHECK-') z=a.findall(y) k=b.findall(y) print(k) ..........................................Can you pleaSE HELP? Also, how can i avoid an error when there is no match?

Comment: You should avoid asking questions under comment section and also spamming same text under every answer.